# how to fill datagridcombobox in vb.net

Tags: sql-server-2005

```
Dim n As Integer = DataGridView1.Rows.Add()
For Each dsrow2 As DataRow In dslocal2.Tables(0).Rows
    DataGridView1.Rows.Item(n).Cells(0).Value = dsrow2.Item("Slno").trim
    DataGridView1.Rows.Item(n).Cells(1).Value = dsrow2.Item("Prodcode").trim
    DataGridView1.Rows.Item(n).Cells(2).Value = dsrow2.Item("Remarks").trim
Next
```

This code is giving an error related to datagridcombobox.

Comment: System.ArgumentException:DataGridViewComboboxCell value is not valid

Comment: Then what is the valid syntax